# Изменить внешний вид сторонего сайта

Tags: php, html, css

Имеется сайт, который постоянно обновляет информацию (т.е. добавляются ссылки для скачки).
Сам сайт cs16-51920a.demki.com, вывожу его на своем сайте путём

```
    <?php
    $homepage = file_get_contents('http://cs16-51920a.demki.com/');
    echo $homepage;
    ?>
```

Что нужно сделать, чтобы можно было оформить внешний вид путём css/html?
Помогите, пожалуйста, заранее спасибо.

Comment: Берете HTML парсер и парсите сайт, затем выводите у себя что нужно и где нужно

Comment: А можно примеры подходящего парсера? 
И не совсем понятно, как это будет в связке работать, если можно, объясните, пожалуйста, детально, спасибо.

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/176635/

Comment: Да какой там парсер, когда они всё в `pre` выводят... Сам распарси и делай что хочешь.